# Query array of objects and set value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "e_id": "1",
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "e_id": "3",
        "total": 0
    }
]
```

Within a forEach loop, I want to increment the `total` value depending on the `e_id`. I have been trying something like this:

```
e.forEach((row) => {
    this.arrayObj[row.e_id]['total']++;
});
```

But this does not work as I think it is using the e_id as an index as opposed to a reference.

Is there a way this can work?

Comment: What is `e` here? You probably need `this.arrayObj.find(o => o.e_id === row.e_id)?.total++`

Comment: [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150)

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
e=[
    {
        "e_id": "1",
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "e_id": "3",
        "total": 0
    }
]

e.forEach((row) => {
    row['total']++;
});
```

Do you need this?